# How to set test datasource for specific models in CakePHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp

Out of the box, CakePHP 1.x has a `default` and `test` datasource. When running unit tests it uses the test database and before each test it can fixturise the data from code, or import data from your default database.

In an app I'm building I have a couple of cases where it would be useful to specify in some of the model fixtures a database other than `test`:

1. the datasource is a web service and the data returned can't easily be replicated with the test database,
2. there are large read-only tables and it is very slow (and unnecessary) to recreate all this data before each test.

I've looked at `CakeTestFixture` but I can't see a good way to do this yet. Perhaps each model really wants to have a `useDbConfig` and `useTestConfig` property?

I can hack my way round this in some cases by doing something like:

```
function startTest() {
    $this->Flock =& ClassRegistry::init('Flock');
    $this->Flock->Sheep->useDbConfig = 'readonly_db';
    $this->Flock->Dog->useDbConfig = 'soap';
}
```

But this will only cover specific dependencies for one test case, and doing this across a suite of tests would be a maintenance nightmare.

Has anyone come across a similar situation and did you have a solution?

Comment: Found this:

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/207-in-test-suite-models-are-forced-to-use-specific-datasource

marked "works-for-me" although no workaround is given. Looks like there is no Cake mechanism to do this, hoping possible to program around this at some point in a non-crufty manner.

Answer (score 0):

create the $test db connection in database.php and cake will take care of the rest. Look at some of the examples in the core test cases and you will see there is nothing special added.

Comment: Hi dogmatic, thanks for your answer. Some of my models use the standard test database (already set up, working fine), some refer to a different datasource so this won't work across the board.

Comment: Starting to think each datasource needs to be setup apart from Cake's usual mechanism, for example I set up a property like `$myModel->customDataSource` that Cake won't mess with. I can then `query()` this object manually. I should point out this hasn't been a fun project to work on...

Comment: maybe you should be mocking the datasource

Comment: It's a good idea, if rather a large and unpleasant interface to mock. But once mocked, it still comes back to the problem of how to specify the mock datasource correctly for each model within the test framework, for example in my nonsense example above, `Sheep` must use `mock_test` and `Dog` must use `mock_soap`.